# XPATH function not recognizing textfield

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm a beginner to python and Selenium and am trying to create a basic code to auto login to a site for me.

https://www.faceit.com/en/login

In tutorials I've found online, ID's make it easier to identify the element, however, the page above doesn't have an ID so I've resorted to using XPATH as a means of identifying the element.

Is there something wrong with my XPATH formatting or something within the code that is causing the issue of not printing my text at all in the fields and subsequently not logging me in?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.faceit.com/en/login")
email_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
email_textbox.send_keys("emailx")

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']")
password_textbox.send_keys("passwordx")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='email']"}

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to wait until your elements will be on their place. Try time.sleep(Some kind of time) or try with one of functions from documentation :)
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Solution:
In browser open developer tools and there is a option button "select an element in the page to inspect it" insepct element you want and in dev tools click right button on it and copy Xpath :)

If this help Vote me up! :)

Comment: would I put that line in between

driver.get("https://www.faceit.com/en/login")
email_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")

Comment: Try like this:
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.faceit.com/en/login")
time.sleep(3)
email_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")

Comment: Tried to incorporate the time.sleep in between those lines like you suggested however I still seem to be getting the same error, even when increasing the sleep time to something like 10 seconds.

Comment: Ok so try this way:

driver.get("https://www.faceit.com/en/login")
time.sleep(10)
email_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/auth-modal-react/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/input")
email_textbox.send_keys("emailx")

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/auth-modal-react/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")
password_textbox.send_keys("passwordx")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/auth-modal-react/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[5]/button")
login_button.click()

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work! I guess the issue stems from the XPATH I'm inputting, is there any guide you can provide me that helps with formatting the path in the way you did? The website has little to no ID's I can easily identify using Selenium and mostly have to depend on XPATHs. Thanks once again.

Comment: Solution added in my answer, for web scraping dev tools realy can by helpful so check that :)

Answer (score 0):

The XPath which you have used in your script are correct and good but looks like the elements were not loaded within the default wait time. So here you can add some wait time before finding these elements.
Also to verify and generating the xpaths you can use the SelectorsHub browser plugin.